# making a div visible but able to click through

Tags: html, css

I have two full screen divs stacked.

css

```css
#border-overlay {
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    top:0; left:0;
    width: 100vw;          
    height: 100vh;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    border: solid 8px white;
}

#button
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    height: 100%; width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    z-index: 15;
}
```

html

```
<div id="border-overlay"></div>
<a id="button" href=""> ... </a>
```

I need the border div on top the button div, however this removes the link function of the button which I want to keep. Essentially the button takes up the full screen so you can click anywhere.

Comment: Any specific reason why you want border div at the top ?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements

Comment: Your code is not clear what you need, can you please describe more?

Comment: I apologize I missed an id. I want the border over everything else on my full page website (all 4 sides not just top), but then it seems to not be able to click the button underneath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No JavaScript needed. Use the CSS [`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) on the div:

```
#border-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 8px white;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/p7eoe07d/)**

Comment: does pointer events have got good cross-browser compatibility as well as screen size responsiveness?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve but you can do the following:

Insert onclick event to your wrapper div that will call click of your anchor tag. Also add to css the pointer cursor and it will look like you press on the anchor.

```js
function clickMe() {
  document.getElementById("button").click();
}
```

```css
#border-overlay {
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    top:0; left:0;
    width: 100vw;          
    height: 100vh;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    border: solid 8px white;
    background-color: yellow;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#button{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    height: 100%; width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    z-index: 15;
}
```

```html
<div id="border-overlay" onclick="clickMe()"></div>
<a id="button" href="/asdad"> Link me up Scottie</a>
```

Comment: the border div is not the button, the button is underneath and changes